# AWS RDS Read Replication Error: "You must enable backups on the master DB instance in order to set up DB instance to DB cluster replication"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, rmysql

I'm trying to create an Aurora read replica from a RDS MySQL database, but I'm getting the following error:

```
You must enable backups on the master DB instance in order to set up DB instance to DB cluster replication...
```

I double checked the source instance and I already have backups enabled.
[image]

What else could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the problem was that my **Backup retention period** was set to **0 days**.
[image]